# How to make Android Notification Never die Like Whatsapp

Tags: android, service, push-notification

I am just trying to make user notification app from an Apache web server to an Android app. In the app I am using Service but sometimes, the service auto-stops and that way the notification will not get recieved by the app. I noticed that WhtapApp always shows notifications without running any services. So how do I get this working in my app similar to WhatsApp or Facebook?

Comment: You probably need a `SyncAdapter` for this (WhatsApp use the same too)

Comment: *thanks* i am trying to use SyncAdapter

Answer (score 1):

How **Facebook** and **Whatsapp** is sending push notification to clients. Please visit:
https://www.quora.com/How-do-Facebook-WhatsApp-and-Twitter-send-push-messages-to-clients-How-is-that-mechanism-better-than-GCM

If you are targeting Android 8.0 (Api level 26) or higher then, you can work around these limitations by using **JobScheduler** jobs. For more details please visit the link below:

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background